# Double curly brace problem

Tags: javascript, template

I created a frontend template page, my page has embedded some javascript. For some lines, I need to use the double curly brace.

one of the line

```
       <a class='media' data-media-index='{{> Index }}'>
        <img data-original="{{> Media.Images.LowResolution.Url }}"
             alt="{{> Title }}"
             style="display:inline-block;"
             class="lazy">
    </a>
```

but it turns out the page source is showing

```
        <a class='media' data-media-index='&#123;&#123;> Index }}'>
        <img data-original="&#123;&#123;> Media.Images.LowResolution.Url }}"
             alt="&#123;&#123;> Title }}"
             style="display:inline-block;"
             class="lazy">
    </a>
```

How can I get this fix and show double curly brace correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add delimiters in jquery will work
change {{,}} to [[,]]

```
delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `\` before to say not to interpret it as code.